Increase SWAP in Ubuntu OS Virtual Machine
I'm in a situation where I can increase the SWAP of the Ubuntu Server 22.04 OS Virtual Machine:
sudo swapoff -a
sudo rm -f /swapfile
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=32M
sudo swapon -s
sudo chown root:root /swapfile && sudo chmod 0600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile && sudo swapon /swapfile

Once everything is done I can see the new SWAP, but when I restart the Ubuntu VM the new SWAP dissapear and go back to the original 8G SWAP.
Just for test, if I apply the above codes in the workstation the SWAP change succefully and after reboot is still there.
Do you have any suggestion?

is funny because people down vote and they hide their head under the ground without telling the reason of the vote or their name ...

I changed the codes used to create the /swapfile but what was really missing (at least to use in the Virtual Machine) was to add it in the fstab file for its automount after every reboot.
